# Qual função do excel devo usar?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Possuo uma lista de nomes do gênero masculino e feminino que preciso determinar na célula da frente qual é o gênero do nome.

A lógica que analisa o nome e diz se ele é masculino e feminino já está pronta, porém, preciso agora criar a seguinte lógica, mas não sei qual função do Excel posso utilizar.

No campo H4 (numero 4) preciso escrever a função que pegará o texto do campo G4 (numero 1) , utilizará este texto no campo C6 (numero 2) onde encontra-se a lógica que determinará o sexo, e pegará o resultado do campo C12 (numero 3) para retornar o resultado no campo H4 (numero 4) .

Preciso aplicar esta lógica para todos os nomes listados na coluna G. Como devo proceder?

[image: Imagem Exemplo Planilha]

Comment: O campo C12 vai ficar variando?

Comment: Sim... Sempre que eu imputar um novo nome no campo C6 e pressionar enter, o campo C12 vai rodar a lógica pra verificar o nome que está no campo C6 e exibir no campo C12 se é MASCULINO ou FEMININO

Comment: Acho que minha resposta conseguirá te ajudar... mas fiquei bem curioso... como está essa fórmula de verificar o gênero! =)

Comment: hahaha não fique curioso, segue o link onde peguei a planilha que já possui a estrutura com a lógica.
http://www.postcogito.org/Kiko/PlanilhaMascFemPtBr.html

muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Legal @Bueno!! Valeu por compartilhar!! Abs boa sorte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma das formas de resolver isso seria o seguinte código (vba) em sua planilha (`Worksheet_Change`):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim celNome As String ' Célula onde deseja verificar o nome
Dim celGenero As String ' Célula que retorna o gênero
Dim colEntrada As Integer ' Coluna onde dará entrada de dados (nomes)

    celNome = "C6"
    celGenero = "C12"
    colEntrada = 7 ' 7=coluna "G"

    ' Verifica se está na coluna de entrada de dados        
    If Target.Column = colEntrada Then
        ' Copia o nome inserido na célula de análise
        Range(celNome).Value = Target.Value
        ' Retorna o gênero após análise
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Range(celGenero).Value
    End If

End Sub
```